# How to open and close modal in functional component using react hooks react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Here I am using React hooks to open and close modal , on TouchableOpacity I am calling fucntion 'handleAddClick' to open modala nd on no and cross icon calling function 'handleClose' to close modal ,
but its not working . Please review my below code and help. In below code I have metion myy full code .
Please sugget .

```
 const HeaderWithPagination = (props) => {
      let { headertext, totalSteps, currentStep, subHeading, cornerBG, closeButton, timeOut, disabletepIndicator } = props
      const goToHome = () => {
        props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())
      }
      const [addModalOpen, setAddModalOpen] = React.useState(false);
    
      const handleAddClick = () => {
        setAddModalOpen(true);
      };
      const handleClose = ()=>{
        setAddModalOpen(false)
      }
      return (
            <>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row',paddingHorizontal: 26,  marginVertical: 40,}}>
    
            <Modal animationIn='zoomIn' animationOut='zoomOut' transparent={true} isVisible={addModalOpen} style={{ marginVertical:'60%',marginHorizontal:'13%', backgroundColor:'#ffffff',borderRadius:20 }}>
                        <Icon onPress={() => {handleClose}} active name={'x-square'} style={{color:'black',alignSelf:'flex-end',fontSize:30,bottom:'10%',right:'8%',}} type="Feather"/>
            <Icon active name={'alert-circle'} style={{color:'#FFD700',alignSelf:'center',fontSize:50,bottom:'8%'}} type="Feather"/>
              <RegularText text={`${translate('AlertBox.gohometitle')}`} textColor='black'  style={{padding:5, marginBottom: 15,textAlign:'center' ,fontWeight: 'bold'}} />
              <View style={{justifyContent:'space-evenly',flexDirection:'row'}}>
                        <Button primary block onPress={() => {handleClose}} style = {{ borderRadius :10,backgroundColor : '#FFD700',width:'25%',alignSelf:'center',top:'10%'}}>
              <Text style = {{color : 'black',alignSelf:'center',padding:50}}>
              {translate('no')}
                            </Text>
                        </Button>
              <Button primary block onPress={() => {goToHome}} style = {{ borderRadius :10,backgroundColor : '#FFD700',width:'25%',alignSelf:'center',top:'10%'}}>
              <Text style = {{color : 'black',alignSelf:'center',}}>
              {translate('yes')}
                            </Text>
                        </Button>
              </View>
                    </Modal>
                <TouchableOpacity   onPress={props.back ? () => props.back() : null}
                   style={{paddingRight:10, }}
                >
                    <Image source={closeButton ? COMMON_CLOSE : props.back ? BACK_BUTTON : null} style={{ height: 25, width: 16, resizeMode: "cover" }} />
    
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'flex-end',}}>
                <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'flex-end',flexDirection:'row'}}>
                {timeOut && 
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginRight: 15}}>
                    { Platform.OS !== 'ios'? 
                     <View>
                       <IconBig type="MaterialCommunityIcons" icon="progress-clock"/>
                     </View> :
                     <View>
                       <IconBig type="Ionicons" icon="ios-timer"/>
                     </View>}
                     <View><CountDown timer={30 * 60} that={this} OnComplete={timeOut ? () => props.timeOut() : null}/></View>
                   </View>
                }
                      <TouchableOpacity style={{paddingHorizontal:10,zIndex:3 }} onPress={() =>handleAddClick }>
                      <IconBig icon="home" type='Feather' style={{color:'#000', textAlign:'center' }} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          </View>
    </View>
    
    
                {/* </View> */}
    
                <Image source={cornerBG && BG_RIGHT_CORNER}
                    style={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        height: 180, width: 300,
                        right: -110, top: -70, resizeMode: "contain"
                    }} />
                <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 26 }}>
                    {headertext &&
                        <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'MTNBrighterSans-Bold', fontSize: 34, color: "#454F63" }}>
                            {headertext}
                        </Text>}
    
                    {!disabletepIndicator &&<StepIndicator
                        currentStep={currentStep}
                        totalSteps={totalSteps}
                    />}
                    {subHeading && <Text style={{
                        color: '#6E6E6E', fontSize: 24, fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Light', fontWeight: '100',
                        paddingVertical: 17.5
                    }}>
                        {subHeading}</Text>}
    
                </View>
    
            </>
    
        )
    }
    export default HeaderWithPagination
```

Answer (score 1):

You defining the function but not calling it correctly

**Change this**

```
 onPress={() => {handleClose}}
```

**to this**

```
 onPress={handleClose}
```

**Complete Code:**

```
const HeaderWithPagination = (props) => {
  let {
    headertext,
    totalSteps,
    currentStep,
    subHeading,
    cornerBG,
    closeButton,
    timeOut,
    disabletepIndicator,
  } = props;
  const goToHome = () => {
    props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
  };
  const [addModalOpen, setAddModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setAddModalOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAddModalOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          paddingHorizontal: 26,
          marginVertical: 40,
        }}>
        <Modal
          animationIn="zoomIn"
          animationOut="zoomOut"
          transparent={true}
          isVisible={addModalOpen}
          style={{
            marginVertical: '60%',
            marginHorizontal: '13%',
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            borderRadius: 20,
          }}>
          <Icon
            onPress={handleClose}
            active
            name={'x-square'}
            style={{
              color: 'black',
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              fontSize: 30,
              bottom: '10%',
              right: '8%',
            }}
            type="Feather"
          />
          <Icon
            active
            name={'alert-circle'}
            style={{
              color: '#FFD700',
              alignSelf: 'center',
              fontSize: 50,
              bottom: '8%',
            }}
            type="Feather"
          />
          <RegularText
            text={`${translate('AlertBox.gohometitle')}`}
            textColor="black"
            style={{
              padding: 5,
              marginBottom: 15,
              textAlign: 'center',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <Button
              primary
              block
              onPress={handleClose}
              style={{
                borderRadius: 10,
                backgroundColor: '#FFD700',
                width: '25%',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                top: '10%',
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{ color: 'black', alignSelf: 'center', padding: 50 }}>
                {translate('no')}
              </Text>
            </Button>
            <Button
              primary
              block
              onPress={goToHome}
              style={{
                borderRadius: 10,
                backgroundColor: '#FFD700',
                width: '25%',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                top: '10%',
              }}>
              <Text style={{ color: 'black', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                {translate('yes')}
              </Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={props.back ? () => props.back() : null}
          style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}>
          <Image
            source={
              closeButton ? COMMON_CLOSE : props.back ? BACK_BUTTON : null
            }
            style={{ height: 25, width: 16, resizeMode: 'cover' }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
          <View
            style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            {timeOut && (
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  marginRight: 15,
                }}>
                {Platform.OS !== 'ios' ? (
                  <View>
                    <IconBig
                      type="MaterialCommunityIcons"
                      icon="progress-clock"
                    />
                  </View>
                ) : (
                  <View>
                    <IconBig type="Ionicons" icon="ios-timer" />
                  </View>
                )}
                <View>
                  <CountDown
                    timer={30 * 60}
                    that={this}
                    OnComplete={timeOut ? () => props.timeOut() : null}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10, zIndex: 3 }}
              onPress={handleAddClick}>
              <IconBig
                icon="home"
                type="Feather"
                style={{ color: '#000', textAlign: 'center' }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

      {/* </View> */}

      <Image
        source={cornerBG && BG_RIGHT_CORNER}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          height: 180,
          width: 300,
          right: -110,
          top: -70,
          resizeMode: 'contain',
        }}
      />
      <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 26 }}>
        {headertext && (
          <Text
            style={{
              fontFamily: 'MTNBrighterSans-Bold',
              fontSize: 34,
              color: '#454F63',
            }}>
            {headertext}
          </Text>
        )}

        {!disabletepIndicator && (
          <StepIndicator currentStep={currentStep} totalSteps={totalSteps} />
        )}
        {subHeading && (
          <Text
            style={{
              color: '#6E6E6E',
              fontSize: 24,
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Light',
              fontWeight: '100',
              paddingVertical: 17.5,
            }}>
            {subHeading}
          </Text>
        )}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
export default HeaderWithPagination;
```